# How plot GridSearch results?

Tags: svm, cross-validation, matplotlib, grid-search

I trained an SVM model with GridSearch

```
svc = SVC()
parameters = {
  'kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
  'C': [0.1, 1, 10]
}

cv = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, cv=5)
cv.fit(v_train, y_train)

print_results(cv)
```

Here is the result I got:

```
BEST PARAMS: {'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}

0.912 (+/-0.037) for {'C': 0.1, 'kernel': 'linear'}
0.763 (+/-0.027) for {'C': 0.1, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.942 (+/-0.045) for {'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}
0.903 (+/-0.044) for {'C': 1, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.94 (+/-0.043) for {'C': 10, 'kernel': 'linear'}
0.928 (+/-0.046) for {'C': 10, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
```

What is the best way to plot this result? in one plot that both contain the `C` parameter and `kernel` with their corresponding accuracy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to have put the results as a Data frame with

```py
pd.DataFrame(cv.cv_results_)
```

And then you have the data in a dataframe which is easier to handle.

For the other question (in your comments), once you have the data in a nice dataframe is just about data visualization. How can you put it in a nice visualization?

The easier are either 2d plots or 3d or even contour plots. By googling them and python you will get nice tutorials on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

*You can use a simple **lineplot**.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it actually helped. What if I had three parameters and accuracy, e.g. C, kernel and gamma, how would you recommend to plot it?